# How to quit or close single simulator from opened multiple simulator in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I run multiple simulator and I need to close one of them. How can i do this? Because I tried to close it like we does in older version of Xcode but can't close.

Comment: Open simulator , under windows menu uncheck `Show Device Bezels`. Then close using red cross icon.

Comment: Select simulator and command + w.

Comment: I am so amused by this question.. Apple has made closing simulator such a mysterious task that developers have to google this query! Long live iOS

Answer (score 397):

Select Simulator.. Go into File Menu -> Close window or press [Command + W ]. It will close the simulator which is on top .

[image]

Go into Windows menu -> uncheck Show Device Bezels. Then you can close using red cross icon on simulator.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any red cross on the simulator.

Comment: you'll have to uncheck Show Device Bezels then simulator will be visible with cross,minimize buttons.

Comment: @bibscy In Simulator 10.1, it's not a red cross but the actual side button you need to press. It will however not close the Simulator for that particular device but will turn off the screen.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a Windows user and forget OS.x (Os.X? oS.x? OS.X? whatever...) even had a menu, far, far away from the app. It isn't 1984 anymore Apple, time to update your UI.

Answer (score 95):

[image]

There are two ways to close particular Simulator form Multiple simulators

1. Long-press power button on the right-top of simulator , then slide to turn off power, a single simulator will be close.
2. Go into File Menu -> Close window or press [Command + W ]. It will close the simulator which is on top

Comment: What about iPhone X?

Comment: You can close any simulator from Xcode 9 with above steps.

Comment: @Llg you can close iphone X , select iphone X simulator and press [Command + W ] to close iphone X

Comment: The first method doesn't work for me (Xcode 9.1), the simulator just restarts. The second one does though.

Answer (score 40):

**1)** Simple way to **close single simulator**

-> Select required Simulator

-> Click Command + W (⌘W).

**2)** If you want to **minimise simulator**

-> Select required simulator

-> Click Command + M (⌘M).

**3)** For **screen shot** of simulator

--> Select required simulator

-->Select Commend + S (⌘S).

**4)** If you want to **rotate simulator(for landscape mode)**

-> Select required simulator

-> Click Command + left arrow or right arrow.

See below screen for left arrow or right arrow

[image]

Comment: Why this has so many likes?  pressing cmd + W will close ALL windows

Answer (score 10):

To long-press power button on the right-top of simulator , then slide to turn off power, a single simulator will be close.

Comment: yes its working but sometime simulator restart when you power off.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, but it was by a program I used called [HyperDock](https://bahoom.com/hyperdock/). It gives a preview of the app windows that are opened when you hover over the icon in the dock. It will give you an option to close the simulator window when you see the preview.

Answer (score 1):

Click Simulator. Open simulator dropdown from the top menu. Click on quit simulator