# How one can able to close few simulator devices instead of all opened simulators in Xcode 9

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode9

First of all apologised if this question is duplicate or making some hard to understand.

As we know that Xcode 9 has feature that we can able to run the app on multiple simulators and we can able to close all of them by force quit or from other options.

Here my query is that, suppose I have open the simulator with devices: iPhone 8, 8 plus and X. Now if I want to close any two of them, then how could I achieved it or what are the ways to manage this case?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to close simulator one by one then follows these steps:-

1 Click on the simulator.

2 Select File, "Close Window", or press Command+W.

Now you can close the all simulator one by one in Xcode9

Comment: please check in details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165635/how-to-quit-or-close-single-simulator-from-opened-multiple-simulator-in-xcode-9